# If inserted record contains text then - TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Pseudo code:
If the newly inserted record contains the text 'Important' then send db_mail

Here is the trigger:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
        IF (columnName.INSERTED = 'Important') 
            BEGIN       
                "Send db_mail query here"
            END
```

Error I am getting:

```
The multi-part identifier "columnName.INSERTED" could not be bound.
```

Comment: Sorry - the dbmail is not my issue here, its getting the pseudo code to work.

Comment: Instead of Pseudo code (unless you want Pseudo answer) please post the exact code and tools to reproduce your issue (by the way @AznDevil92 is correct regarding sending email directly from trigger, once solution is add message to queue and using service broker to send the email)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to query pseudotable [`INSERTED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-2017):

```
IF (columnName.INSERTED = 'Important') 


IF EXISTS (SELECT *
          FROM INSERTED
          WHERE columnName = 'Important')
....
```

Please not that SQL Server trigger is statement based so you will need some kind of CURSOR to handle multiple rows. Also sending mails directly from trigger may affect performance.

Comment: No... you do no need any "`kind of CURSOR`" but simply push all the data to queue and using service broker to send the email (for example)

Comment: @RonenAriely With cursor part I wanted to point out that in SQL Server we don't have 'FOR EACH ROW' functionality. I agree that Service Broker is the way to go if OP needs(online processing). Another approach could be some job that for every x minutes read content of table and send email + change status.